# Complete Solution

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the complete solution $x = x_p + x_n$ for each $Ax = b$.
>
> a) $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 2 & 5 & 7& 6\\2& 3& 4& 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \\ x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4 \\3\\5 \end{bmatrix} $
>
> b) $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 3 \\ 6 & 3 & 9\\4 & 2 & 6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}10 \\30\\20 \end{bmatrix} $

So I'm working on finding the complete solutions for these two problems, but I feel as if I've done something wrong in both problems. [image: Here's my work]

My concern with part (a) is that $x_3 = 0$, but it's not free. In that case, is my particular solution still correct?

For part (b), rows 2 and 3 become $0$, but $b_2$ and $b_3$ both equal ten. In this case, would $x_2$ and $x_3$ be free?

What is and isn't free affects what my $X_n$ (nullspace solution(s)), so I'm not sure if I've done those correct either.

Edit: A note on complete solutions: For Ax = b, the complete solution is X = $X_p$ + $X_n$, where $X_p$ is the particular solution (what b becomes, including 0's as free variables), and $X_n$ is a nullspace solution based on what variables are free.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please first try to learn $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I l$\LaTeX$'d the question, but will leave your work to be $\LaTeX$'d by you as an exercise.

Comment: I appreciate it, I was confused how to implement it, I tried an edit without using the $'s. Thanks :D

Comment: Also I may have forgot my entire knowledge of a complete solution, (I don't recall ever learning the concept), I agree with your row reduction though. It might be helpful with a link to some notes, or a brief summary

Comment: @mdave16 turns out the solutions for part B are (10, 30, 20) and i wrote (10, 20, 30). That solves my question about part (b)

Comment: $(-2,-2,0,1)$ is obviously not in the null space of the first coefficient matrix. I suspect that you made a sign error somewhere in your row-reduction. Similarly, $(-1,1,1)$ is not in the null space of the second matrix. For that one, it looks like you’ve erred in reading a basis from the rref.

Comment: Even your particular solution for (a) doesn't work. $2(2)+4(-1)+6(0)+4(0) \ne 4$

Comment: The particular solution is not the solution to the entire problem, since I didn't do reduced row echelon form, just row echelon form.